# Silverlight 3 missing ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged event workaround?

Tags: silverlight, scrollbar, scrollviewer

I want to be notified of changes to the VerticalOffset of the vertical scrollbar of a ScrollViewer. In WPF there is a ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged event, but in Silverlight 3 this is missing. Does anyone know a workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use element binding, here is a daft example:-

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="60" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollSource">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock>Hello</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>World</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>Yasso</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>Kosmos</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=ScrollSource}" />

</Grid>
```

As the `ScrollViewer` is scrolled the Text property of the TextBox is advised of the new value.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Instead of in WPF just subscribing to the ScrollChanged event, I now bind a custom dependency property to the scrollviewer's VerticalOffset, and use a callback for the dependency property to be able to do something with the changed values in code. At least it works :p

Comment: http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jlikness/archive/2010/05/18/making-the-scrollviewer-talk-in-silverlight-4.aspx

Answer (score 3):

There's an easier solution that featured on the silverlight forums:

```
protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
{    
    // Assumes you only have one scrollviewer (e.g. fullscreen ScrollViewer)
    var scrollbar = LayoutRoot.GetVisualDescendants()
        .OfType<ScrollBar>()
        .FirstOrDefault();

    if (scrollbar != null)
        scrollbar.Scroll += ScrollBarScroll;

    return base.ArrangeOverride(finalSize);
}

private void ScrollBarScroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a good link which i found while googling, it also has some sample code which i haven't checked out.

http://dotplusnet.blogspot.com/2010/05/scrollviewer-scroll-change-event-in.html